# arraylist in combobox then listbox

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

I have an array-list called arraylist and the data is read in from a text file - then into classes (called teacher and student) then stored as follows into the array-list:

```
[0]TEACHER
[1]STUDENT
[2]STUDENT
[3]TEACHER
[4]STUDENT
```

Each teacher has its own details as does each student.

How would i populate a combobox with all the teachers from the array-list - then depending on which teacher is selected in the combobox.... the corresponding students to the teacher that was selected populates in another listbox..

I was thinking to populate the combobox with the teacher something like this:

```
    //method to populate combobox (cboWhichTeacher)
    {
        foreach (Teacher t in arraylist)
        {
            string selectedTeacher;
            selectedTeacher = t.getTeacherName();
            cboWhichTeacher.Items.Add(selectedTeacher);
        }
        cboWhichTeacher.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and to get the corresponding students i am not too sure:
        }

```
    public static int studentSelected = -1;

    private void lst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTeacher.studentSelected = lstStudent.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void cboWhichSwitch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        foreach (Teacher t in arraylist)
        {
            foreach (Student s in s.getAllTeacherStudents())
            {
                output = ("Teacher " + s.getstudentname() + "no students");
                lstStudent.Items.Add(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I can't tell, is this java or another language?

Comment: c# sorry ill add some more detail?

Comment: You should show the array declaration, is it in object[] ?
And also precise the client tech that you use... And also you will probably find plenty of examples if you search well in the internet ...

Comment: @rad public static ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();